# Mass create AD Accounts

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a CSV containing a large number of names (students) and basically would like to create accounts in AD for them - placing them in default groups, and giving them all the same password to begin with.

How can this be done in Powershell? Or any other cmd line tool?

Comment: The first several hits on Google for "[create active directory user accounts csv](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+active+directory+user+accounts+csv)" should be enlightening.

Comment: Looking at your last few questions, do you do any of your own work or just hoping SO will do most of it for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the Active Directory Powershell Module that's in the [RSAT tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887)
Then import the csv to an array of objects, and use the AD module to create users. Something like:

```
Import-CSV c:\yourfile.csv | Foreach-Object {
    New-ADUser -Name $_.Name -AccountPassword $_.AccountPassword -WhateverParameter $_.SomevaluefromCSV
}
```

This isn't a place to ask for complete solutions, so that's as far as I wanna go so I don't encourage others to make questions this "open".